# How to call cookies from js to observer

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I have set cookies in js with bellow code

```
 getSelectedValuecc: function() {
            jQuery(function () {
            jQuery("#paytm_payment_profile_id").change(function () {
            //alert('select chnage');
            var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();
            alert("Value: " + selectedValue);
            $.cookie('cookie_name', selectedValue,{ path: 'http://vaibhav.local/complaint/customer/index' });
            var temp = $.cookie('cookie_name');
            alert("cookie - " +temp);
            //jQuery('input[name="payment[method]"]').attr("disabled",true);
           if (selectedValue !=''){
               jQuery("#pay").show();
               jQuery("#address").show();
            }else{
                jQuery("#pay").hide();
                jQuery("#address").hide();
            }
            alert("Value: " + selectedValue);
            if(selectedValue == 'vsquare'){
               jQuery("#address").html("V Square Building 1st Lane, DwarakaNagar,Visakhapatnam-530016,AP.,India").show();
               jQuery("#paytm").click();
               return true;
            }
            if(selectedValue == 'pavanpalace'){
               jQuery("#address").html("A-1,Pavan Palace,near telugu thalli Flyover,Station Road, Dwaraka Nagar,Visakhapatnam-530016,AP.,India").show();
               jQuery("#paytm").click();
               return true;
            }
            return selectedValue;
        });
    });
    },
```

I want to get this cookies on observer with bellow code

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $cookieValue = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie(\Iksula\Complaint\Controller\Customer\Index::cookie_name);
        echo($cookieValue);
}
```

i am getting error **Undefined class constant 'cookie_name'**

Answer (score 0):

Change following line

> \Iksula\Complaint\Controller\Customer\Index::cookie_name

To

> cookie_name

Now your code looks like

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $cookieValue = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie('cookie_name');
    echo($cookieValue);
}
```

Comment: its not working for me